# aws-cdk Associate Lambda Function with CloudFront Web Distribution

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm trying to create a CloudFront Web Distribution using [aws-cdk](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cdk). I'm able to successfully create the web distribution but I haven't been able to figure out how to associate a lambda function yet.

Below is a snippet of my Typescript aws-cdk code to create the CloudFront Web Distribution. I removed some of the code that's not relevant.

```
new cloudfront.CloudFrontWebDistribution(this, 'RetsFilesCDN', {
        originConfigs: [
            {
                s3OriginSource: {
                    originAccessIdentity: cfAccess, /* A CfnCloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity object created in earlier code */
                    s3BucketSource: files /* S3 bucket created in earlier code */
                },
                behaviors: [
                    {
                        compress: true,
                        defaultTtlSeconds: 172800,
                        isDefaultBehavior: true,
                        maxTtlSeconds: 31536000,
                        minTtlSeconds: 0
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    });
```

The CloudFormation code that I'm trying to get it to generate is something like this:

```
RetsFilesCDNCFDistribution6F414E1A:
Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
Properties:
  DistributionConfig:
    CacheBehaviors:
      []
    Comment: CDN for files from the Real Estate RETS services that BranchCMS
      integrates with
    DefaultCacheBehavior:
      AllowedMethods:
        - GET
        - HEAD
      CachedMethods:
        - GET
        - HEAD
      Compress: true
      DefaultTTL: 172800
      ForwardedValues:
        Cookies:
          Forward: none
        QueryString: false
      MaxTTL: 259200
      MinTTL: 172800
      LambdaFunctionAssociations:
        - EventType: origin-response
          LambdaFunctionARN: lambdaFunctionArnHere
      TargetOriginId: origin1
      ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https
    DefaultRootObject: index.html
    Enabled: true
    HttpVersion: http2
    IPV6Enabled: true
    Origins:
      - DomainName:
          Fn::GetAtt:
            - RetsFilesC9F78E92
            - DomainName
        Id: origin1
        S3OriginConfig:
          OriginAccessIdentity:
            Fn::Join:
              - ""
              - - origin-access-identity/cloudfront/
                - Ref: RetsFilesAccess
    PriceClass: PriceClass_100
    ViewerCertificate:
      AcmCertificateArn: arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:666445282096:certificate/25d4967c-c29a-4d11-983f-86d709769372
      SslSupportMethod: sni-only
```

The exact part that I can't seem to generate is:

```
LambdaFunctionAssociations:
   - EventType: origin-response
     LambdaFunctionARN: lambdaFunctionArnHere
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: At the time of this writing, adding raw CloudFormation overrides is the only way as you already found out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best technique, but the following worked for me.

```html
import cdk = require('@aws-cdk/cdk');
import cloudfront = require('@aws-cdk/aws-cloudfront');
import lambda = require('@aws-cdk/aws-lambda');


export class MyStack extends cdk.Stack {
    constructor(parent: cdk.App, name: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
        super(parent, name, props);

        // Create the Lambda function
        const lambdaFunc = new lambda.Function(this, 'MyLambda', {
             YOUR_LAMBDA_PROPERTIES: HERE
        });

        // Create the CloudFront Web Distribution
        const cf = new cloudfront.CloudFrontWebDistribution(this, 'MyCDN', {
            YOUR_CLOUDFRONT_PROPERTIES: HERE
        });

        /**
         * THIS IS THE BEGINNING OF THE SOLUTION
         */

        // Get the CloudFront Distribution object to add the LambdaFunctionAssociations to
        const cfDist = cf.findChild('CFDistribution') as cloudfront.CfnDistribution;

        // Manually add the LambdaFunctionAssociations by adding an override
        cfDist.addOverride('Properties.DistributionConfig.DefaultCacheBehavior.LambdaFunctionAssociations', [{
            EventType: 'origin-response',
            LambdaFunctionARN: lambdaFunc.functionArn + ':2'
        }]);

        /**
         * END OF SOLUTION
         */ 
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like there is an api change.

`cf.findChild('CFDistribution')` should now be `cf.node.findChild('CFDistribution')`

Comment: I'm getting an error with this solution: `Lambda@Edge cannot retrieve the specified Lambda function. Update the IAM policy to add pe rmission: lambda:GetFunction for resource: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:rest-of-arn:2 and try again. (Service: AmazonCloudFront; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidLambdaFunctionAssociation; Request ID: uuid)`

Comment: There's an issue open on github. https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/1474

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to associate a newly created function (lamda@edge / cloudfront function) with an existing cloudfront distribution?
The above code only seems to work for a newly created distribution.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this property for the assosiation of lambda function to your cloudfront cache behaviour

```
import { CfnDistribution.CacheBehaviorProperty } from '@aws-cdk/aws-cloudfront';
CfnDistribution.CacheBehaviorProperty.LambdaFunctionAssociations
```

[for more information click on this link](https://awslabs.github.io/aws-cdk/refs/_aws-cdk_aws-cloudfront.html#@aws-cdk/aws-cloudfront.CfnDistribution.CacheBehaviorProperty.lambdaFunctionAssociations)

Comment: That you for that. I'm still a bit confused about how I integrate that into my code and assign the lambda association to my cloudfront web distribution.

Comment: [Updated link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-cloudfront.LambdaFunctionAssociation.html) since these things change so quickly.